# Не работает кнопка

Tags: bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Название сайта</h1>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
                             
                            </button>
                    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Название компании</a>!-->
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы забыли подключить jquery или bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Название сайта</h1>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">А что не работает?</button>
                    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Название компании</a>!-->
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: уже в ответе иправлено

Comment: Кнопка не работала, почему-то описание проблемы не добавилось... Код, что выше работает как нужно, спасибо. Пока не понял в чем была проблема